# How can I write this in one line without duplicate dictionary name and key?

Tags: c#, operators

how can I write this in c# (latest version) in **one line without dublicate dictionary name and key**:

`someDict[key] = someDict[key].MakeSomeChanges(1);`

I found something like that:

`_ = someDict[key].MakeSomeChanges(1);`

but unfortunately that not assign changed value.

```
public static int[] MakeSomeChanges(this int[] array, int a)
{
    //some logic
    return x.ToArray();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your suggestion `_ = someDict[key].MakeSomeChanges(1);` only works with reference types.

Comment: Do you need to return a new array? If not, you could simply make the modifications to the values in the array, as you're accessing the same array as held in `someDict`.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information. Do this in "one line"? Why? Are you verifying if that "key" exists before you access the value? And what do you mean by "without dublicate dictionary name"? What "Name"?

Comment: @Isitar Given that it is an array, and it doesn't work, clearly, that's not true.

Comment: Its need to return a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if following helps and it's also not one line, but it could be a way to avoid the repetition and is reusable for any modification or dictionary type.

Since you already use an extension method, add another one:

```
public static void Modify<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue intialValue, Func<TValue, TValue> modify)
{
    bool exists = dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue existingValue);
    TValue value = exists ? existingValue : intialValue;
    dict[key] = modify(value);
}
```

With this on board you could use:

```
someDict.Modify(key, new int[0], arr => arr.MakeSomeChanges(1));
```

Where `MakeSomeChanges` could be a method call(like above) or an inline logic.